# Unity AddComponent return null

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Monobehavior with or without a Rigidbody2D component. I want to get it or create it if needed.

The **AddComponent**, returns null on my game. Often, not every time,
the log appeared.

Using:

- Unity 2019.2.19
- Android Platform

```cs
void Start()
{
    Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>() ?? 
        gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    if (rb == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No way to be here!");
    }
}
```

I can remove the ?? and do this in multiple lines, it doesn't change the error.

Do you have a solution to get the Rigidbody2D component?

Comment: did you try `var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); if(!rb) rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigibody2D>(); if(!rb) Debug.LogError("No way to be here!", this);` ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same result. The AddComponent<Rigidbidy2D>() return null.

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console?

Comment: No message in the console. I thinks it's a bug with AddComponent

Comment: I have rolled this question back to the last state where it was purely a question. I have also transferred the answer material to your (deleted) answer. Please undelete the answer so that everyone can see it, and then (optionally) accept it with the tick/check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The coalescing operator doesn't works with MonoBehavior **and** I need to get the Component a third time to make it work. It seems that the AddComponent does not work with Rigidbody2D.

This code works:

```
Rigidbody2D  rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

if (rb == null)
{
    rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

if (rb == null)
{
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this:

```cs
void Start()
{
    Rigidbody2D rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    if(rb == null)
    {
        rb = gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    //this check is redundant cause the null check is done previously, but is done to maintain your structure
    if (rb == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No way to be here!");
    }
}
```

**Note:** Also have in mind that `Components` are derived from `UnityEngine.Object`, which doesn't support ***null-coalescing operator***.

Comment: @derHugo yes, but it is to maintain the OP structure to not lead to confusion (added a comment to explain this ^^)

Comment: I actually didn't mean the null check which isn't very expensive but rather `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` after `gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` is redundant ...

Comment: It's not redundent because AddComponent doesn't work every time...
Please watch my solution in the edited post